# Java sort list containing list on index value of list?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a nested list like below (but it has 1,000's of the `holder` lists within the one main list). Say I need to sort the main list `listEmailData` by the value for each of its `holder` lists on the `holder.get(2)` index. I can't seem to figure out how to do this any advice is appreciated.

```
ArrayList listEmailData;

ArrayList holder = new ArrayList();

listEmailData.add(3)
listEmailData.add(323)
listEmailData.add(2342)

listEmailData.add(holder)
```

EDIT: To clarify, I have a list where each list entry contains a sub-list, within this sub-list a specific index contains a value that is a ranking. I need to sort the main list based on this ranking value within each sub-list.

2ND EDIT: Thanks for the help on this, got it working but its seems that its putting larger numbers first and large numbers later, I was hoping to reverse this so it goes from largest to smallest as I am

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should implement `Comparator<T>` to compare lists, then call

```
Collections.sort(listEmailData, comparator);
```

Your comparator would have to compare any two "sublists" - e.g. by fetching a particular value. For example:

```
public class ListComparator implements Comparator<List<Integer>>
{
    private final int indexToCompare;

    public ListComparator(int indexToCompare)
    {
        this.indexToCompare = indexToCompare;
    }

    public int compare(List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second)
    {
        // TODO: null checking
        Integer firstValue = first.get(indexToCompare);
        Integer secondValue = second.get(indexToCompare);
        return firstValue.compareTo(secondValue);
    }
}
```

Note that this is using generics - hopefully your real code is too.

Comment: sorry if I'm missing something obvious but I am not quite sure how to make this compare the thousands of entries in a list and then sort the list accordingly, I can see that calling compare() would sort between 2 of the list inputs

Comment: @Rick: The comparator compares any two lists. You use `Collections.sort` on the *list of lists* using this comparator, as per the first part of the answer.

Comment: @Rick - You would not call `compare()` directly, that is handled by `Collections.sort(listEmailData, new ListComparator())` for you.

Comment: ok thanks, I think the c in Collections needs to be capitalized, I'm fairly ignorant of collections in Java so that threw me off at first I think as I thought it was a regular variable object name

Comment: @Rick: Sorry, yes, that was a typo. Oops.

Comment: pardon my ignorance on this as well but how do I get the sorted list back out, if I try `listEmailData = Collections.sort(listEmailData, new SortListContainingList());` I get a type mismatch error

Comment: @Rick: Collections.sort has a void return type - it sorts the collection in-place. So just call it without trying to assign the value back to `listEmailData`.

Comment: ahh ok, I trie that but was on the wrong index :) thanks, will try again

Comment: This seems to be putting them in reverse numerical order, is it just me or am is it actually like that and I have to do something extra to make it go so it puts the smallest numbers in first and then the largest numbers in last

Comment: @Rick: It should already be doing smallest first. Could you either edit your answer with a full sample we can try, or perhaps just mail me with it? A short but complete console app would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks I think I have it reversed from what I am trying to do as I am trying to have it output the larger ones first when looping through, is there a way to make it output it this way from the Collections comparator?

Comment: @Jon, sorry I had it backwards, I need it to do largest first, sorry just have been up too long working on the project so I'm getting things mixed up :)

Comment: @Rick: Okay, that's easy. Just change the line in the comparator to: `return secondValue.compareTo(firstValue);`. That will reverse the nature of the comparison.

Comment: cold you post the complete working example so that it can used for reference.I need the `PSVM` for this example.Would be appreciated if you could post it as well.